# all shapekeys are edited at once

Tags: shape-keys

Im very new to the concept of shapekeys, so I dont know, wether this is a bug or a mistake in my hands.

I modelled this heart and tried using shapekeys as a way to animate the cardiac cycle.

I am in the standard position of the heart.
no vertex groups, no settings regarding the Object Data tab.

I hit the plus button to create a basis shapekey

only "Relative" and the box behind the name is ticked.

I hit the plus button another time.

I slide the value to 1.

I sculpt a bit.

Whenever I slide the Value factor, nothing happened, because my basis shapekey seems like also edited.

How can I solve this issue?

[download .blend here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52226)

Comment: maybe I miss something but I can't see any shapekeys in your objects, you've only created vertex groups, which is a different thing

Comment: Thats because I send an older saving by mistake. Just delete the 2 VertexGroups and create the shapekys in your manner. I just want to find the cause of this weird behaviour.

Comment: could you please edit your question and share the current version of your file?

Comment: here you go, I hope you find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually both the 2 shapekeys are identical, the object is deformed because you've given it a *Multires* modifier. So delete this modifier or at least deactivate it and make the mesh deformations you need in *Edit* mode with the shapekey called *Key1* selected.